# Запись в массив нужные параметры php

Tags: php, массивы

Дорогие гуру помогите разобраться, не понимаю как составит алгоритм есть массив:

```
  $massive = array(
    '0' => array('propertyname' => 'цвет','value' => 'red'),
    '1' => array('propertyname' => 'версия', 'value' => 'android')
  );
```

Из массива **$massive** нужно собирать такой:

```
   $result = array(
        'цвет' => array('value' => 'red'),
        'версия' => array('value' => 'android')
    );
```

т.е разделит **propertyname** в отдельный массив в цикле **foreach** в массиве **$massive** могут быть и другие параметры например:

```
'2' => array('propertyname' => 'память', 'value' => '16')
```

ну и естественно добавит этот в **$result** как отдельный параметр:

```
'память' => array('value' => '16')
```

надеюсь понятно объяснил.

Comment: ну логично что пробежаться циклом по одному массиву и собрать так, как необходимо в другой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = array();

foreach ($massive as $elem) {
     $result[$elem['propertyname']] = array(
          'value' => $elem['value']
     );     
}
```

Comment: У Вас отработал?

Comment: Спасибо помогло. Жаль что я не очень умею строит алгоритм.

Comment: Да, отработал. У Вас нет?

Comment: @mega94 тут нет алгоритма и нечего тут строить. Просто нужно подумать и сделать. Задача простейшая.

Comment: ок тогда, я не разворачивал

Comment: если  $massive = array(
            '0'=> array('propertyname' => 'цвет','value' => 'red'),
            '1'=> array('propertyname' => 'версия', 'value' => 'android'),
            '2'=> array('propertyname' => 'версия', 'value' => 'iphone')
        ); то как подобрать 2`value` в существующий массив `версия`

Comment: Если 'propertyname' могут дублироваться, тогда у Вас не получиться создать нужный массив, так как ключи не могут быть одинаковыми

Comment: почему не получится? для начало нужно посмотреть `$result` есть ли такой то ключ если есть нужно в добавок добавит просто `value` и все? так построит не получится?

Comment: Верно. Вы можете добавить проверку на существования ключа, например функцией array_key_exists

Answer (score 2):

Все очень просто же

```
<?php
$massive = [
    '0' => ['propertyname' => 'color','value' => 'red'],
    '1' => ['propertyname' => 'version', 'value' => 'android']
];

$result = [];

foreach ($massive as $item) {
    $result[$item['propertyname']] = $item;
    unset($result[$item['propertyname']]['propertyname']);
}

print_r($result);
/**

Array
(
    [color] => Array
        (
            [value] => red
        )

    [version] => Array
        (
            [value] => android
        )

)
*/
```